# Are Equestria's Princesss Celestia and EG Principal Celestia aware of each other?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim, equestria-girls

Being Celestia, one might assume they know quite more than what is shown. The fact Principal Celestia is unfazed at the end of EG with all the destruction going around and the SFX from the magic battle outside hints at that.

But is there any source on how much they know of each other?

Comment: In *Friendship Games*, Principal Celestia seems to accept that the Twilight Sparkle that is competing in the games is not the same Twilight Sparkle that appeared to help during the last two magical events. It is lightly implied that she at least vaguely understands the difference. But if she's aware of Princess Celestia herself, it's not clear. In *Equistria Girls*, it is strongly implied that Princess Celestia is aware of the complications, which is why she forbids the rest of the Mane 6 from helping Twilight, and probably one of the reasons why she's delegating this to Twilight.

Comment: mumble, thinking of it, I will have to check what the comics implies about the mirror. If it works like the one in Reflections (and I seem to recall it is the same mirror or a second mirror modeled after the first one), Princess Celestia would have very precise reasons to figure out that the mirror could lead to another "twisted reflection" of Equestria

Comment: @Ellesedil make your comment into an answer, i have a green checkmark for you.

Answer (score 3):

### Princess Celestia is almost definitely aware of Principal Celestia's existence at some point, but it is unclear if Principal Celestia is aware Princess Celestia exists.

In *Equistria Girls*, it is strongly implied that **Princess** Celestia is aware of the complications involved when visiting the alternate universe that Canterlot High inhabits. She forbids the rest of the Mane 6 from helping Twilight, which suggests that she's delegating this to only Twilight because she knows Twilight is not present at Canterlot High, which won't cause any undue confusion.

Of course, after Princess Twilight Sparkle recovers the crown and returns to Equstria, she has shared her experiences with other ponies. We know this because she explains why the rest of the Mane 6 can't help Twilight when she is about to return to Canterlot High in *Rainbow Rocks*, which they seem to accept and understand without objection.

So, if **Princess** Celestia wasn't definitively aware of **Principal** Celestia before then, she probably is now.

In *Friendship Games*, **Principal** Celestia seems to accept that the Twilight Sparkle that is competing in the games for Crystal Prep is not the same Twilight Sparkle that appeared to help during the last two movies, which had significant magical events occur at Canterlot High. It is lightly implied that she at least vaguely understands the difference. But if she's aware of **Princess** Celestia herself, it's not clear.